# Liferay login API from Ionic App

Tags: ionic-framework, authentication, liferay, liferay-6

I want to know  if there is any API/Webservice in side Liferay that allows one to use mobile apps especially built with Ionic to do remote authentication and pull data from database

Comment: https://github.com/salvatejero/cordova-liferay-plugin

Comment: What data do you need?Check for the rest API services in Liferay,using a json call,passing on the required authetication params,you should be able to retrieve all you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no special API for Login/Logout out of the box.

Complete list of Out of the BOX Web Services and detailed information on each can be found at
whaterver-url/api/jsonws

Example : https://www.liferay.com/api/jsonws

**Why there is no Out of the Box API For Login/Logout.**

All API's mentioned in above Link needs a basic Authentication. So in each request you need to pass username & password which will throw permission denied, if credentials are not valid.

Comment: You are welcomed :) You can accept as answer if it helped or write your own answer on what's the solution if it didnt helped.!

Comment: Ok. Will paste my answer! Thanks